# Databricks: How to get the cluster tags in %SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, select, tags, databricks, sentence

Currently with the statament %SQL query: "SET" I can get the value of the tags defined in the cluster.

```
%sql
SET spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterName;
```

But, how can I use these values in a "SELECT" statement to define a condition, define the "FROM" value or create a new column?

```
%sql
---for example:
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE column1 = spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterName;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

%sql
    SET spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterName;

is for setting the cluster name and in return its gives as to what is the name of the cluster .